# How to remove quotes from a file using awk

Tags: csv, awk

I am dealing with a CSV file with over 500,000 rows.

I wish to change any lines like below

```
2164-09-13 17:00:00,"""some text here""",,"moretext",
```

to

```
2164-09-13 17:00:00,"some text here",,"moretext",
```

the lines that have multiple double quotes, I want to change them to a single pair of quotes.

Comment: Use: `sed 's/"\+/"/g' file`

Comment: @sat if you put that as an answer with some explanation of the regex, I would gladly accept the answer.

Comment: Don't you have any lines like `x,""foo"",y` or more normal CSV quoting/escaping like `x,"abc""def""ghi",y` also in the file to deal with?

Comment: @EdMorton `grep "\"\"" myfile.csv` only finds two rows. Both have data similar to what I have in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

g is for global (will replace more than just the first instance of a pattern on a single line), s is for substitution (s/regexp/replacement/), + is escaped so that sed knows this is not a literal in the pattern but part of the regular expression which signifies 'find 1 or more occurrences of the pattern'.

```
echo '2164-09-13 17:00:00,"""some text here""",,"moretext",' | sed 's/"\+/"/g'
```

Comment: Please note that `\+` is a _GNU_ `sed` extension. To make the command portable, use `sed 's/"\{1,\}/"/g'`

Comment: `\{1,\}` is the POSIX-compliant [BRE (basic regular expression)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) equivalent of the widely used `+` quantifier (duplication symbol), which GNU chose to back-port to BREs as `\+`. POSIX `sed` only supports BREs, but both GNU and BSD/macOS `sed` support EREs (extended regular expressions) via the `-E` (`-r`) option - albeit in different flavors - where `+` works as expected. You read `\{1,\}` as: at least `1` occurrence, up to an indefinite number (`,`), with the `\{` and `\}` delimiting the range.

Answer (score 2):

Given what you've told us, all you need is:

```
$ tr -s '"' < file
2164-09-13 17:00:00,"some text here",,"moretext",
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '2164-09-13 17:00:00,"""some text here""",,"moretext",' |awk 'gsub(/"""/,"\42")'

2164-09-13 17:00:00,"some text here",,"moretext",
```

Comment: ++, but there's no need for  `\42`, you can escape a `"` as `\"`: `gsub(/"""/,"\"")`